# How to make absolute-positioned "markers" on map image maintain position responsively

Tags: javascript, css

please can anyone help with this "interactive map" I am trying to build?

The code is saved here (https://github.com/wkan17012021/test-map) and you can view a demo here (https://wkan17012021.github.io/test-map/plainJSWithMarkers.html).

**Resources I used to cobble this together:**

https://matemarschalko.medium.com/interactive-image-maps-and-closable-popups-with-html-and-css-only-31fe36c70092 (how to implement HTML5 map tag and css popups)

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp (for ref)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XygqEKdroPw (markup and styling for the markers)

I would like to create a map with pins/icons/markers on countries that direct the viewer to interact with them. When they click on one of the markers, a pop-up should appear which could redirect to a page with similar content for that country.

Problem I'm having is making it responsive. You'll notice that the markers move about (mostly vertically) as you go from mobile -> desktop width. Ideally, they should stay in the same position within the country. This is more noticeable for countries of smaller landmass as the marker moves out of the 'clickable' region to activate the popup.

**What have I tried so far?**
Make the markers smaller / media queries, but to no avail.

Using an img editor to draw on circles to the image is a no-go, the animation is an important aspect to this feature.

Looked to see if anyone else had this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=interactive+map+image+responsive
If you found a relevant SO problem with solution please forward the link.

Any suggestions? Can it be done with css and plain JS alone?

Constructive feedback is welcome.

Thanks

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css"></link>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>


<body class="vsc-initialized">
    <h1>Responsive Image Map with Vanilla JS and pulsing markers</h1>
    <div class="map">

        <img src="./WORLD copy_1000x525.png" usemap="#image-map" alt="world map with bluie tone">
        <span class="markerBelize"></span>
        <span class="markerBrazil"></span>
        <span class="markerSwitzerland"></span>
        <span class="markerThailand"></span>
        <map name="image-map">
            <area target="" alt="brazil" title="brazil" href="#brazil"
                coords="329,409,341,401,341,390,357,385,364,372,366,360,377,344,368,332,354,330,342,325,332,325,335,315,320,320,312,318,308,312,302,317,296,325,288,321,286,329,281,339,275,346,286,354,297,349,309,359,318,369,317,381,328,390,321,404" shape="poly">
            <area target="" alt="belize" title="belize" href="#belize"
                coords="255,302,207,255" shape="rect">
            <area target="" alt="switzerland" title="switzerland"
                href="#switzerland" coords="470,174,510,211" shape="rect">
            <area target="" alt="thailand" title="thailand"
                href="#thailand" coords="744,320,743,309,735,301,733,289,739,289,749,285,746,275,738,276,732,269,727,273,728,285,729,296,735,313" shape="poly">  
        </map>
        
        <div class="popup popup-belize" id="belize">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Flag_of_Belize.svg/1920px-Flag_of_Belize.svg.png"
                alt="belize flag">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">Belize</a>
            <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
        </div>
        <div class="popup popup-brazil" id="brazil">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1632184078944-b8a9cd828a57?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80"
                alt="brazil flag">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">Brazil</a>
            <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
        </div>
        <div class="popup popup-switzerland" id="switzerland">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1618493075021-1bbe5deebedf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1548&q=80"
                alt="switzerland flag">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">Switzerland</a>
            <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
        </div>
        <div class="popup popup-thailand" id="thailand">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1645421105080-525091cfead0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80"
                alt="thailand flag">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">Thailand</a>
            <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
        </div>

    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.css

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

div {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

img[usemap] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  height: auto;

  width: 100%;
}

.popup {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 120px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.9);
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: opacity 300ms, transform 300ms;
}

.popup-brazil {
  top: 70%;
  left: 37%;
}

.popup-switzerland {
  top: 10%;
  left: 30%;
}

.popup-thailand {
  top: 48%;
  right: 0%;
}

.popup-belize {
  top: 58%;
  left: 2%;
}

.popup:target {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.popup > .close {
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: -10px;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}

.popup img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .popup {
    font-size: 14px;
    max-width: 100px;
  }
}

.map span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #b62584;

  /* animation */
  animation: highlight 1.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes highlight {
  100% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.markerBrazil {
  top: 66%;
  left: 32.5%;
}
.markerBelize {
  top: 51%;
  left: 22.5%;
}
.markerSwitzerland {
  top: 34.5%;
  left: 48.5%;
}
.markerThailand {
  top: 50%;
  left: 71.5%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .markerBrazil {
    top: 66%;
    left: 32.5%;
  }
  .markerBelize {
    top: 52%;
    left: 23%;
  }
  .markerSwitzerland {
    top: 35.5%;
    left: 48.5%;
  }
  .markerThailand {
    top: 50%;
    left: 72%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have different position values in the index.css for the media screens.
So just use the same values like below and the issue is fixed or if no need for different media screens, just remove them.

```
.markerBrazil {
    top: 66%;
    left: 32.5%;
}
.markerBelize {
    top: 52%;
    left: 22%;
}
.markerSwitzerland {
    top: 36%;
    left: 48%;
}
.markerThailand {
    top: 54%;
    left: 72%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
.markerBrazil {
    top: 66%;
    left: 32.5%;
}
.markerBelize {
    top: 52%;
    left: 22%;
}
.markerSwitzerland {
    top: 36%;
    left: 48%;
}
.markerThailand {
    top: 54%;
    left: 72%;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi @TominCode, thanks for responding promptly. I tried the suggestion, and it certainly works. There was still some movement observed between screen widths but some minor adj to top / left properties was enough to resolve my issue. Thanks!